# Running Data From External Classes

Tags: vb.net, class

Over the past few months I have been struggling to find a way to execute external un-compiled classes from my program.

EXAMPLE:

I have a simple run button on a windows forum. When that run button is pressed I wan't to run the Main sub in run.vb. (Run.vb is not part of the program and is located in a directory)

Is their a way to do this without using .dll's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run VB.Net code as I see. There are a bunch of classes in System.CodeDom.Compiler namespace to deal with .Net source code.
See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5472/Compiling-NET-code-on-the-fly
There is a good example with explanation here.

If you want to run VB6 code, the only way is compiling it to dll and then dynamically load and run. Or you can use VBscript if it will suit you.
In fact, CodeDom compiles your code to dll assembly too, but keeps it in memory, so you don't need to clean up any mess after you app is dead